# AuthenticationOptions' AutomaticAuthenticate property meaning

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Looking [at asp.net documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authenticationoptions.automaticauthenticate?view=aspnetcore-1.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_AuthenticationOptions_AutomaticAuthenticate), I can't figure out what does the AuthenticationOptions.AutomaticAuthenticate Property do.

It says "If true the authentication middleware alter the request user coming in". What is being altered? The request user? In what way is it altered?